# Stream and map a list to a map in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to do something like the following with java 8 and lambda expression.

```
Map<String, String> headers = service.getFieldNamesInOrder(eventType).stream()
.map(f -> serviceClassInfo.getNameforField(f).collect(Collectors.toMap(<streamed field>, <result of map>)));
```

Like this:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
for (String field : headerFieldNames) {
    String name = service.getNameforField(field);
    headers.put(field, name);
}
```

I want to stream a list, take one element and get another value for it. And afterwards I want to add the streamed element as key and the result from the method as value.
Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicate elements?

Comment: An element should be added only once for every field.

Comment: What you have is clearly more readable than doing this with the stream API. Don't unnecessarily change this to use stream. Just because you can use stream API to accomplish something doesn't mean that you should always do it, there is a fine line in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

- the `(a,b)->b` is a merge function in case of duplicates. It uses the most recent one.

```
Map<String, String> headers = headerFieldNames.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(field -> field,
                        field -> service.getNamefoField(field),
                        (a, b) -> b));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like

```
  Map<String, String> headers = headerFieldNames.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(f-> f, f -> service.getNameforField(f)));
```

Or

```
Map<String, String> headers = headerFieldNames.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), f-> service.getNameforField(f)));
```

**Warning:** It is code throws expection in case of you have duplicate.